# Badges do not work in pinned website on Windows 10

Tags: windows, notifications, microsoft-edge, badge, pinned-site

I am setting up my website https://simbiat.ru to have proper tags and webconfig to be used with pinned websites, but I've ran into trouble: pinned site does not show badges or notifications, even though linked to proper (although test) xml files with for badge and notification respectfully.
And not only that: pinned sites on Win10 ignore logos (and colors) set in meta tags and webconfig and take the largest one from webmanifest instead, tasklists work only when pinned from IE11. Yet it does not look like there is any indication in official documentation, that this was abandoned.
So my question is, whether this has been abandoned (and replaced with other stuff as per https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/11/16/improving-notifications-badging-microsoft-edge/) and documentation was not updated or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: About the badges, you can refer to [this reply](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/articles/improving-notifications-and-badging-in-microsoft-edge/m-p/1878680/highlight/true#M3845). I try the demo in it and badges work well in Edge. You can refer to [this article](https://web.dev/badging-api/#try-it) about how to use the App Badging API. Please make sure you have installed the app in Edge before you test the badges. About the tasklists, I didn't find information about it either.

Comment: that's kinda my point, though: specification on MSDN says, that there is a msapplication-badge meta, which should refer to appropriate XML file using Badge Schema. It should be supported, but it looks like it's not. Badging API is a different thing, although it does serve same purpose.

Comment: Then I think you should try to use App Badging API which will definitely work in Edge Chromium.